# setState doesn't render textfield inside of map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, react-hooks

I tried to let users to modify their business info.
One user may have more than one business.
I put this info on

```
  const [franchises, setFranchises] = React.useState(null);
```

franchises will contain those kind of objects in array.

[image: franchises]

I have an issue with onChange in textField components.
It is not rendered when franchises state updated.

I will share my code below.

```
export default function MyPage(props) {

 React.useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
     if (auth.userExtraInfo.role === constant.role.washmate) {
        const washmates = await Promise.all(auth.userExtraInfo.washmateDocs.map((v) => {
          return api.getWashmate(v)
        }))
        setFranchises(washmates)
       
        setWashReturns(returnPointArray)
        
      } 

    })()

  }, [])

let washmateView = (<><DesText>매장 정보</DesText>
    <EmptySpace />
    {franchises && franchises.map((v, i) => {

      return (<>




        <FixableTextField
          title="본사 이름"
          fixable={restitleFixable}

          onChange={(e) => {

            console.log(e.target.value)
            console.log("franchises modified", franchises)      ///will show changed franchises objects, but only one character will be added entirely.
            console.log("v?", v)
            let mArray = franchises
            mArray[i].data.storeName = e.target.value

            setFranchises(mArray)
          }}
          value={franchises[i].data.storeName}                  ///!!!!Here is the problem !!!!!
          fixButtonTapped={() => {
            setRestitleFixable(!restitleFixable);
          }}
        />

        <AddressForm
          fixable={addressFixing}
          bfixButton={true}
          mainAddress={mainAddress}
          setMainAddress={setMainAddress}
          restAddress={restAddress}
          setRestAddress={setRestAddress}
          fixButtonTapped={(a) => {
            if (addressFixing) {
              setAddressFixing(false);
            } else {
              setAddressFixing(true);
            }
            window.alert(mainAddress, restAddress);
          }}
        />
      </>)
    })}

  </>)

return (
    <Page>
      <AppBar backLink="/main" menu={true} />
      <EmptySpace />
      <SubTitle>내정보</SubTitle>
      <EmptySpace />
      <UpText>이메일</UpText>
      <OutLinedTextField value={auth.user.email} disabled />
      <Link href="/forgotpassword" justifycontent="flex-end">
        비밀번호 변경하기
      </Link>
      <EmptySpace />
      <EmptySpace />
      <EmptySpace />
      <UpText>파트너스 종류</UpText>
      <OutLinedTextField value={role} disabled />
      <EmptySpace />
      <EmptySpace />
      <EmptySpace />
      {auth.userExtraInfo.role === constant.role.franchise && franchiseView}
      {auth.userExtraInfo.role === constant.role.washmate && washmateView}
      {console.log(washmateView)}

      {/* washmate, franchise */}
      <EmptySpace />
      <EmptySpace />
      {/* deleiveryView */}
      {auth.userExtraInfo.role === constant.role.delivery && deliveryView}

      <EmptySpace />

      <ContainedButton>회원탈퇴</ContainedButton>
      <ContainedButton>로그아웃</ContainedButton>
      <EmptySpace />
    </Page>
  );
}
```

Here is FixableTextField components

```
export default function FixableTextField(props) {
  const fixable = props.fixable;

  const marginSide = css.marginSide;
  const bothMarginside = marginSide * 2;
  const marginTop = css.marginTop;
  return (
    <>
      <UpText>{props.title} </UpText>
      <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
        <TextField
          variant="outlined"
          disabled={!fixable}
          value={props.restAddress}
          {...props}
          style={{
            margin: `${marginTop}px ${marginSide}px`,
            width: `calc(100% - ${marginSide * 2}px)`
          }}
        ></TextField>

        <Link
          onClick={() => {
            props.fixButtonTapped();
          }}
          justifycontent="flex-end"
        >
          {props.fixable ? "완료" : "수정"}
        </Link>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

This code will give me output of only one character added by pressing any input.
(for example, carwash + pressing ta, will give me only carwasha)

[image]

storeName : 워시메이트 was original value,
when I pressed 1 to 4,
I got this result.

I've investigated the variable washmateView, So put this code in parent directly, but have same result.

Another trial was putting FixableTextfield component directly in the parent, but have same result.

I am thinking the issue caused by map function.

If anyone knows reason why or a way of writting correct code,
let me know.
thank you.

Comment: The problem is that if you do `let mArray = franchises; ...  setFranchises(mArray)` your state never actually changes because you are refferring always to the same array. if you change `let mArray = franchises` with `let mArray = [...franchises]`, thus creating a new array, it should solve the issue.

Comment: @secan yes, it really works. copy and reference :) thank you.